# Remove one line of code from all activitys/Classes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

Okay, i was wondering how to remove one line of code from all my activities .
I know i have the same line of code in all my activities, i was just wondering if i could remove it easily instead of doing it activity by activity.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

- In the top menu select Search / File (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>).
- In the dialog that opens, type the "Containing text" and then hit "Replace".
- In the new dialog enter the string to be replaced with.

I think you should carefully use this feature.